# Is a welcome message when user returns to conversation possible with BotFramework?

Tags: .net-core, botframework

I'm using botframework with a bot that runs in Skype and Telegram. I want the bot to send a welcome message when the user returns, but I want the message sent before the user sends their message to the bot. I've tried using onMembersAdded, but this does not fire when the user has already started a conversation with the bot, at least in Skype and Telegram. Is there anyway to send a message to a returning user with Botframework?

Comment: I don't have any experience with the Skype or Telegram channels, but maybe [proactive messages](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages) may work?

Comment: Could you please tell me what the version of your bot application?

Comment: The  question is what you mean by 'When the user returns'. From the bots\channels perspective, the converation is ongoing. I guess you need to use state to implement something like this

Answer (score 0):

In a word, no.

I have experienced the same with Teams channel. I'm not 100% sure the Skype and Telegram channels work the same, but with Teams the conversation never "ends". In fact, if you leave the conversation in the middle of a dialog prompt, it will still be expecting an answer to that prompt days later. So from a bot perspective its the same if the user comes back in 5 minutes or 5 days. In order to send a proactive message, you would still need some sort of event to trigger that message when the user returns. Unless Skype or Telegram provide some method to send an event when a user returns focus to the conversation, you won't be able to do this before the user sends a message.